# NativeScript Firebase plugin execution order

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, nativescript

I'm learning NativeScript/Angular 2 and would need to get help with this issue.

In order to implement a multi-role login system within the Firebase platform I thought about this solution

1. Login the user through Firebase authentication
2. Query the `/stores/` path for a `store` which has a `merchantEmail` field same as the e-mail that has just logged in
3. If I find it, I set the `store` ID inside a `BackendService` service which uses `getString/setString` to store tokens, then route to a `MerchantDashboardComponent`
4. If I don't find it, just route to a `BuyerDashboardComponent`

This is part of my code in the `login.service`:

```
    login (email: string, password: string) {
    return firebase.login({
        type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).then(
        (result: any) => {
            firebase.query(
                (_result) => { // Here I set BackendService.storeID
```

Inside the `.query()` callback I am assigning the tokens I need in the application.

This is the method I'm using in my `login.component`:

```
doLogin () {
    this.isAuthenticating = true;

    if (!this.validateEmail()) {
        alert("Please insert a valid email");
        return false;
    }

    this.loginService.login(this.email, this.password).then(
        () => {
            this.isAuthenticating = false;

            if (BackendService.loginError)
                alert(BackendService.loginError)
            else if (BackendService.storeID != '') {
                this.router.navigate(['/merchant-dashboard'], {clearHistory: true});                   
            }
            else {
                this.router.navigate(['/home/categories'], {clearHistory: true});
             }

        }
    );
}
```

Everything works except for the fact that the Merchant gets routed to the Buyer dashboard. I've managed to discover that the execution order is not what I expected to be, in fact:

1. `firebase.login()` gets executed and returns a Promise
2. `.then()` handler is executed inside the `doLogin()` method
3. Only after this, the `firebase.query()` method completes the callback and my tokens are available, but `doLogin()` has already navigated the user because `storeID` is still empty when I need it

I hope I've been clear as much as possible.
Thanks for your attention.

Greetings,
Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was in the login service method.
I now *return* the `Promise` generated by `firebase.query()`, which causes `then()` calls to chain in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Yep that was exactly was I was going to propose to wrap it in a promise and create a chain.

example code

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

firebase.login({ loginArguments })
    .then((result: any) => {
        var onQueryEvent = function (result) {
        };

        return firebase.query(
            onQueryEvent,
            "/owner",
            {
                // query arguments follows here
            }
        ).then(res => {
            return res;
        })

    })
    .then(finalResult => {
        console.log(finalResult);
        try {
            resolve(finalResult);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
});
```